# Why didn't Uchiha Itachi get himself the Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

To make an Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan, you need to transplant another Mangekyo Sharingan, right?

Itachi had awakened his Mangekyo Sharingan when Shisui died, and Shisui had gave his eye to Itachi.  So why didn't he transplant that eye and make his Mangekyo Sharingan eternal?

Comment: *To make an Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan, you need to transplant another Mangekyo Sharingan, right?*, no, just transplation is not enough, should be the person with strong blood ties ideally a sibling

Comment: To add to this question, Itachi was the main actor in the Uchiha clan massacre. In fact, it has him who killed his own parents. Instead of Sasuke, couldn't he implant his parents' instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There could be a couple reasons: Two plausible ones were mentioned by Makoto. As we all know, the Sharingan is a pair Dojutsu and so one would need 2 Mangekyou together in order to awaken the Eternal Mangekyou in both of their eyes. The other reason was also stated by Makoto, is because it has been mentioned that the 2 individuals must be related by blood and it makes sense since the only 2 people who have actually ever done this were Sasuke and Madara and they used the Mangekyou's of their siblings.

As for the reason why he did not use his father's Mangekyou, it could be because Itachi knew that he was dying and saw no point in achieving Eternal Mangekyou, just to die to an incurable sickness. He probably knew he wouldn't have enough time to reap the benefits of the Eternal Mangekyou. For more info on his sickness check out this thread; [was it ever stated if Itachi was already dying?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/48553/was-it-ever-stated-canonically-that-itachi-was-already-dying-when-he-fought-sasu)

The last reason is what I would call "***an overwhelming level of Love mixed in with a strong guilty conscience***". Itachi wiped out his entire clan to protect Konoha from the coup that the Uchiha were planning, but couldn't kill his brother because he loved him more than everything else. Itachi most definitely knew how terrible his acts were and right from that moment planned to make amends for it  by dying at the hands of his kid brother, who would try to avenge the entire clan. Itachi most likely also concluded that Sasuke would have had no chance against him if he had the Eternal Mangekyou, and therefore decided to really fight his younger brother later on after his eyes had deteriorated in such a manner that they would be close in strength and not a one sided battle.

[image]

So it was actually because of Sasuke! He knew he was dying and preferred to die at his brothers hand. By doing that, he used his death to make Sasuke stronger. In order to make the fight a bit fair, Itachi decided to let Sasuke have the upper hand (by fighting him while he was partially blind and sick).

Comment: And yet the stupid little brother failed to defeat the partially blind and sick older brother who intentionally hold back in improving his powers.... Sorry couldn't keep my self from writing it! Awesome answer though! thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

[Danzo had stolen one of his eyes](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shisui_Uchiha#Personality) before Shisui could have given it to Itachi.  An Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan has never been created with just one eye; it has always been *pairs* of eyes.

Also, one other condition for the Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan is that there has to be very strong blood ties between two people.  Itachi and Shisui are both cousins at best, so the blood tie is weaker than between Itachi and Sasuke, for instance.  It would be unlikely that an Eternal Mangekyo would have formed from Shisui's single eye.

Answer (score -1):

Eternal Mangekyou only requires spare eyes. However, to obtain the Mangekyou you need to be attached to someone, like a sibling/close friend (this explains why Obito never lost his vision and why Kakashi was able to use the perfect sussano).

Itachi didn't get the eternal mangekyou because he just didn't want to. He did not want to take his father's/anyone else's eyes, because maybe he felt very guilty.

Answer (score -1):

The existing answers are incorrect. You cannot get an Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan just by changing to any other pair of eyes, you can only do so if those eyes are from a brother (blood related). This was precisely explained.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references to support your answer.