# Why did Itachi say that he needs to get someone's MS to get EMS while Sasuke only had a normal Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

In the fight between Sasuke and Itachi, Itachi said that to get Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan (EMS), he must transplant his brother's eyes that have to be Mangekyou Sharingan (MS). However, Sasuke didn't have MS yet.

So, even if Sasuke did get his normal Sharingan eyes, how could he get the EMS?

Comment: Never thought about it but just checked maybe it's a plot hole if I didn't overlook something

Comment: Dupe of [Can the Eternal Mangekyō Sharingan be obtained by implanting a normal Sharingan?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/36974/2516) (but not yet answered)

Comment: That guy was asking if it has  to be ms or just normal sharingan to get ems. What i mean is why did itachi say that he needs to get someones ms to get ems but he was after sasuke that had just normal sharingan

Answer (score 4):

Because he actually didn't want them. He was trying to relay that information to Sasuke before his death. He gave that information about EMS to Sasuke so that Sasuke could obtain EMS after his death if he wanted.

Plus Itachi was on the verge of blindness. So even if Sasuke had normal sharingan Itachi could at least have sight, that's a good excuse.

Comment: True, it  was all part of Itachi's plan. That was just an [excuse lol](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/46567/why-uchiha-itachi-didnt-make-his-mangekyo-sharingan-eternal/49589#49589)